# How to turn off "Shake to wake camera" on Nexus 5?

Tags: camera, activation

Ages ago, while running Lollipop, I found a setting to allow activation of the camera whilst locked. All you have to do is shake the phone. I'll give that a try, I thought. After all, I can always cancel it if I don't like it. However, the thing is way too sensitive and has been driving me mad taking photos of pocket lint and my feet mostly

I can't find the setting to turn it off, despite a great deal of menu exploring and even checking the 'similar questions' panel currently to my right as I type. Upgrading to Marshmallow hasn't got rid of it.

I've got a sneaky suspicion it's a function of a 3rd-party app since there's nothing obvious in the Android settings screen or in the app settings.

Has anyone else come across this or actually figured how to disable it?

Comment: try clearing cache and data of settings and camera app.

Comment: This is new. I never heard this feature on stock Camera app from KitKat to Marshmallow (I have Nexus 4 & 5). Should be caused by 3rd-party app (e.g. [Shake](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adl.appshaker), [QuickCamera](http://www.addictivetips.com/android/quickcamera-launch-the-camera-app-with-a-twist-of-your-wrist/), etc). Otherwise, it's a feature on Motorola X or Droid Maxx, which is certainly not your phone. Try to search your installed apps on **Settings - Apps - Downloaded**. Also, are you using custom launcher?

Comment: It wasn't a specific app, more like an extra feature of something else I'd downloaded.  I'll have a go at clearing the cache, although if the setting to turn the feature on and off isn't part of the camera I'd expect it not to work. Worth a try though.

Comment: This question was closed because Nexus 5 and its stock camera app (Google Camera) don't have a built-in "shake to wake camera" feature, making the underlying issue unclear.

Answer (score 0):

On the Moto X (2013), this setting is called *Quick Capture*, and appears in the camera app's settings.  It's likely to be in a similar place on the Nexus.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: camera settings]